# CMSMS htaccess rewrite for ListIt2 module

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i'm creating a website with CMS made simple version 1.11.11 and i use the listit2 module version 1.4.1 .

Now this module only can generate urls in this form:
http://example.com/listit2/item-alias/page-id

Now, i don't care about the page id which is used to show the correct template,
but since this is a multilingual website i would like listit2 to apear behind my (virtual) language folder:
 http://example.com/lang/listit2/item-alias/page-id

so i added 2 rewrite lines in my htaccess file, 
right before the general rewrite rules of CMSMS.

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^lang/listit2 [NC]
    RewriteRule ^lang/listit2(.*)$ listit2$1

    # Rewrites urls in the form of /parent/child/
    # but only rewrites if the requested URL is not a file or directory

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
```

but that doesn't seem to work since it generates the summary overview instead of a detail page like the content from http://example.com/listit2/page-id

How, can i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the trick

```
    
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    #Virtual folders for listit2
    RewriteRule ^lang/listit2(.*)$ index.php?page=listit2$1

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a .htaccess issue. It is a URL generation issue within the ListIt2 module.

Within your summary template, instead of using the standard variable for the detail_url, you will need to put your own custom URL in the href.

For example something like this (this code isn't test, check documentation for the actual variables)

```
<a href="{root_url}/lang/listit2/{$item->item_alias}/{$content_id}" title="Read more about {$item->title}">Read More...</a>
```